# Do I put all items together for a factor analysis?

Tags: factor-analysis, confirmatory-factor

I have 3 items measuring risk-perception and 5 items measuring willingness to comply and I want to run a Factor Analysis. Do I put all 8 items together for a factor analysis, or do I run two separate analyses, since they are measuring different things?

Answer (score 0):

If you already know which item is supposed to measure which factor (so this is confirmatory factor analysis), the main difference between two separate models and one overarching model is that in the latter case you can estimate the correlation between factors while in the former you cannot.

Should this be exploratory factor analysis, you would have one model so that you can see how tightly the items fit together in each group vs. how different the from each other the two groups are.